# Integrate by parts $\int_0^\infty w' \bar w$; any nice expression for $w$ complex-valued?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $w$ be a complex-valued function of $t \in [0,\infty)$. At $t \to \infty$, it decays to zero. And $w_t(0)$ is prescribed.

Is there any nice expression for the integral
$$\int_0^\infty w' \bar w$$
where $\bar w$ is the conjugate of $w$?

This is because I have an ODE of the form $aw'' +bw' +cw =0$ and I want an energy estimate, so I test with $\bar w$. But the problem is the I don't know how to handle the $w' \bar w$ term by integration by parts, since I end up getting something like $Re(w)Im(w)'$ which I can't do much about.

Comment: Are the coefficients of your ODE complex? Where is the $b$ in your integral?

Comment: @gerw the coefficient $c$ is complex with positive real part, $b$ is complex with zero real part and $a$ is real. Theyare all constants so I didn't include it in the expression for the integral.

Comment: Have you tried to separate the resulting identity into its real and imaginary part?

Comment: Do you mean the integral? Yes, and I end up getting somthing some nice terms + $Re(w)Im(w')$ (or some multiple thereof) a term that I don't know how to handle.

Comment: You might add your current calculation to the question. This might help to trigger some effort by others.